# Handling long-lived branch (like 2 weeks) integration on superprojects?

Tags: git, workflow, git-submodules

We are using gitsubmodules (SM).
We have several big superprojects (SP) that contain a lot of SM and nested SM.
For each repo (SM or SP), we have a master, a develop and some feature branches.

My question is the following:
Shorter is better as speaking of branches, but in the case we are building in a first SP a disruptive feature (that breaks SM interfaces with the other SP), how could we handle such painfull integration with the other SPs?

- shall we wait for all superprojects to be compliant to the feature before merging this feature into develop branches of SM?
- shall we merge the feature with the develop branches of SM and then "force" other SP that want to be on the develop SM branches to be compliant to the new feature, or create their own temporary branches if they don't have time (because of an ongoing release) to merge their project with the new feature.

Note 1: Disruptive changes are in most case a development environment update, because our environment is not yet well designed. In the process of making in this environment changes easier, we have to create those big changes. More changes now for less changes later.

Note 2: our environment is made out of makefiles, but I guess any language could have been used so I didn't mention it.

Answer (score 1):

Your various independent (I assume) super projects implicitly agreed to adhere to the common API of your submodules' interfaces. These submodules are supposed to be somewhat generic and not reliant on how their clients (the SPs) use them. By unilaterally changing the API, you have reversed the flow of dependencies and broken backwards compatibility.

So how to handle this "API upgrade"? Two options are overloading (aka extension) and versioning. You didn't specify the nature of the breaking changes: are they specific to one SP or are they a general advancement of the API as a whole?

- Generally, and especially if the updates do not apply to all SPs, the API should follow the [Open-closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle). That means putting your changes into new functions and calling them from those SPs that need them, leaving the remaining ones intact. This is the preferred option and I suggest you try to (re-)do your changes in a way that doesn't break compatibility.
- if your changes are supposed to (eventually) be rolled out to all SPs, you will have more work and your options are various tradeoffs about when to do the work. You first have to decide how gradual you want this transition to be.

  - A hard cut would mean tagging the legacy versions in all SMs and switching the SPs to it. Then you can migrate one SP at a time to the new version. This means depriving the not-yet-migrated SPs of new API features.
  - Alternatively, you move your API changes to a new branch and force all SPs that want to use them to switch to this branch. When all SPs are covered, you can finally merge the branch to the mainline (dev or master). This potentially creates a very long lasting branch.
  - Both options require you to maintain two lines of development which is a hassle. That's why it's better to follow the Open-closed principle to avoid this issue.

Comment: your answer is quite interesting. I must add that currently our interfaces are not well designed, and so there are some redesign work to make them generic. I'm not talking only about software code, but more about compilation environnement.
How would your adapt your answer knowing this? thank you

Comment: @GuillaumeD can you be more specific about what you mean by compilation environment?

Comment: we are using makefiles, but SP's/SM makefiles interfaces are badly written.

Comment: I'm not saying using makefiles is the good way, but I have to deal with it.

Comment: I'm trying to build a generic interface for all SM so they can be integrated well with SPs and changes would be less a pain in the boot.

Comment: Are the SM makefiles included or referenced in the SPs? I don't see how that changes the general approach I've outlined.

Comment: "Are the SM makefiles included or referenced in the SPs?" sometime yes, sometimes not. I'm trying to homogenise all interfaces.

Comment: I can't tell you ad-hoc what the best solution is (you could ask another question) but with regards to the current question, does the situation now prevent you from changing the code? If yes, you would have to settle on one approach and unify your build pipelines first.

Answer (score 0):

Ditching SM in favor of separate git-repos reduces a lot of pain and timewaste.

Two of those disruptive events alone should take more time than doing
the split (regardless of amount of SM).

Apparently it happens rarely,
i.e. the SM-usage/interfaces stay stable, meaning easier to split.

Comment: git-repo is not an option, and IMO would not solve this problem, which is not about the tool but the process.

Comment: If there are separate projects each SP can work with a different own release-branch. In that you separate the functionality/interface in a codebase you circumvent managing the "glue" interfaces too. Think of like maven dependencies instead of inherent SM dep.

Answer (score 0):

Your first bullet point seems like a better option, because in your second you risk introducing breaking changes for an indefinite time.

However, in these scenarios its really hard to avoid breaking changes so then, I think it really comes down to what your smallest testable unit is. Look for whether your SP is testable without any of the SMs or are there certain SMs that are independent of the SPs, then go with those first.

Side-note: If your project and submodules are adhering to the dependency inversion principle, this should be fairly easy. You would start with merging the high-level modules first.

Comment: "your second you risk introducing breaking changes for an indefinite time." 
You also risk introducing the same issue with the first option, as some SP would not be ready until some time, so the feature that needs to be added would not be on the main branches of the SPs.